# "systemctl list-timers" shows last executed dates that are far in the future

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

When I run `systemctl list-timers`, the last executed dates are far in the future. For example, this is part of the output:

```
$ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                          LEFT                    LAST                          PASSED                  UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Sat 2017-08-19 02:29:16 CEST  6h left                 Wed 2017-08-16 02:50:57 CEST  2 days ago              systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Sun 2092-06-29 22:30:00 CEST  74 years 10 months left Sun 2092-06-29 00:22:17 CEST  74 years 10 months left rsnapshot-daily.timer        rsnapshot@daily.service
Mon 2092-06-30 00:00:00 CEST  74 years 10 months left Sun 2092-06-29 00:22:17 CEST  74 years 10 months left fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
Mon 2092-06-30 00:00:00 CEST  74 years 10 months left Sun 2092-06-29 00:22:17 CEST  74 years 10 months left logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Mon 2092-06-30 00:00:00 CEST  74 years 10 months left Sun 2092-06-29 00:22:17 CEST  74 years 10 months left man-db.timer                 man-db.service
```

When I checked my backup, which should be triggered by the `rsnapshot-daily.timer` job, I noticed that it stopped working about one week ago. Thus, it looks like the systemd timers are partly broken on my system.

I assume the problem will go away if I reboot my machine. Still, I am curious if it is a known problem and whether there any workarounds?

Restarting the timers did not make a difference (e.g., `systemctl restart rsnapshot-daily.timer`). The last executed dates are still in 2092.

I'm using systemd version 234.11-8 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update (2022-08-08):** A bugfix has been [merged now](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/24131). Hopefully, the following workaround is no longer needed.

**Update (2023-01-28):** Unfortunately, the bugfix had [to be reverted](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/25083) in the 252 release since it caused another regression. Thus, the problem is still open and the workaround below is still relevant.

---

Until the [Systemd bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6036)  is fixed, I used this workaround to get the timers in sync again:

- Touch all files with broken timestamps in `/var/lib/systemd/timers`
- Reboot the machine

Now, `systemctl list-timers` shows sane output again.

According to the [Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers), deleting the timestamp files should also be safe:

> If a timer gets out of sync, it may help to delete its stamp-* file in `/var/lib/systemd/timers`. These are zero length files which mark the last time each timer was run. If deleted, they will be reconstructed on the next start of their timer.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6036 is reopened on Oct 20, 2022

Comment: @QiLuo Thanks, I edited the post to include the information.

Answer (score 5):

This is systemd timer behaviour that is triggered by a system clock that was at one point erroneously set to a time in the future, the year 2092 in your case:

- Zeal Jagannatha (2017-05-26). *[systemd timers do not reset after a time/date change](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6036)*.  systemd bug #6036.  GitHub.